# Linter gives warning/error after reinstalling VS Code

Tags: r, windows, visual-studio-code

After installing VS Code on my new computer, the indent linting standard for the R Extension seems to be ignored. Instead it assumes to be indent 2, where previously it was 4. Where would I change that setting to avoid getting linter errors like these

[image]

Supposed setting file: "C:\Users....vscode\extensions\reditorsupport.r-2.8.2\R.lintr"

```
linters: linters_with_defaults(
line_length_linter(120), indentation_linter(4), cyclocomp_linter = NULL, object_name_linter = NULL, object_usage_linter = NULL)
```

Context: Windows, VS Code 1.85.1, R extension 2.8.2

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to place a `.lintr` file in your `HOME` directory - they also list some other placement options here: https://lintr.r-lib.org/dev/articles/lintr.html#other-configuration-options. You'll need to restart VS Code after you do that.

The formatting of it is very picky - this is mine and the trailing line is very necessary.

```
linters: linters_with_defaults(
    line_length_linter(120), 
    commented_code_linter = NULL,
    object_usage_linter = NULL,
    trailing_blank_lines_linter = NULL,
    trailing_whitespace_linter = NULL,
    indentation_linter = NULL,
    object_name_linter = NULL
  )
encoding: "UTF-8"
```